# Get an element by index in jQuery

Tags: jquery, dom, get

I have an unordered list and the index of an `li` tag in that list. I have to get the `li` element by using that index and change its background color. Is this possible without looping the entire list? I mean, is there any method that could achieve this functionality?

Here is my code, which I believe would work...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var index = 3;
</script>

<ul>
    <li>India</li>
    <li>Indonesia</li>
    <li>China</li>
    <li>United States</li>
    <li>United Kingdom</li>
</ul>

<script type="text/javascript">
  // I want to change bgColor of selected li element
  $('ul li')[index].css({'background-color':'#343434'});

  // Or, I have seen a function in jQuery doc, which gives nothing to me
  $('ul li').get(index).css({'background-color':'#343434'});
</script>
```

Comment: The two ways you're using there return dom elements rather than jQuery objects so the call to .css will not work on them. Darius' answer below using eq is what you want.

Answer (score 298, accepted):

```
$(...)[index]      // gives you the DOM element at index
$(...).get(index)  // gives you the DOM element at index
$(...).eq(index)   // gives you the jQuery object of element at index
```

DOM objects don't have `css` function, use the last...

```
$('ul li').eq(index).css({'background-color':'#343434'});
```

**docs:**

`.get(index)` **Returns: Element**

- Description: Retrieve the DOM elements matched by the jQuery object.
- See: https://api.jquery.com/get/

`.eq(index)` **Returns: jQuery**

- Description: Reduce the set of matched elements to the one at the specified index.
- See: https://api.jquery.com/eq/

Answer (score 26):

You can use jQuery's [`.eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) method to get the element with a certain index.

```
$('ul li').eq(index).css({'background-color':'#343434'});
```

Answer (score 19):

You can use the [eq method or selector](http://jqapi.com/#p=eq-selector):

```
$('ul').find('li').eq(index).css({'background-color':'#343434'});
```

Comment: You could have make the selector simpler with  `$('ul li').eq(index).css({'background-color':'#343434'});`

Comment: But in most browsers the selector `$('ul').find('li')` is faster. [[1](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11503220/1293700), [2](https://dab1nmslvvntp.cloudfront.net/wp-content/uploads/jquery4u/2013/04/jquery-parent-child-selectors.png)]

Answer (score 5):

There is another way of getting an element by index in jQuery using CSS [`:nth-of-type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-of-type) pseudo-class:

```
<script>
    // css selector that describes what you need:
    // ul li:nth-of-type(3)
    var selector = 'ul li:nth-of-type(' + index + ')';
    $(selector).css({'background-color':'#343434'});
</script>
```

There are other [selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started/Selectors) that you may use with jQuery to match any element that you need.

Answer (score -1):

You could skip the jquery and just use CSS style tagging:

```
 <ul>
 <li>India</li>
 <li>Indonesia</li>
 <li style="background-color:#343434;">China</li>
 <li>United States</li>
 <li>United Kingdom</li>
 </ul>
```