# How to hide a HTML row by index?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm attempting to hide certain rows of my HTML table based on their index but I get the error:

> TypeError: $rows[0].hide is not a function

What am I doing wrong?

HTML:

```
<tbody id="searchable">
        <c:forEach var="lot" items="${pageResult.entries}" varStatus="status">
            <tr title="<c:out value='${lot.description}'/>">
            <td><c:out value='${lot.nom}'/></td>
            <td><fmt:formatNumber value="${lot.id}" pattern="0000"/></td>
            <td><c:out value='${lot.priorite}'/></td>
            <td>
                <form:form class="actionForm" action="detail" method="POST">
                    <input type="hidden" name="lotId" value="<c:out value='${lot.nom}'/>"/>
                    <input type="submit" class="action editer" value="Editer"/>
                </form:form>
                <form:form class="actionForm" action="supprimer" method="POST" onsubmit="return confirm('Confirmer la suppression?')">
                    <input type="hidden" name="lotId" value="<c:out value='${lot.nom}'/>"/>
                    <input type="submit" class="action supprimer" value="Supprimer"/>
                </form:form>
            </td></tr>
        </c:forEach>
</tbody>
```

Javascript:

```
var $rows = $('#searchable tr');
$(document).ready(function(){
    $rows[0].hide();
});
```

Comment: try changing `var $rows` to `var rows`

Comment: `$rows.eq(0).hide();`

Comment: @Advaith `$` in js varname has no meaning, it is like any other valid character

Comment: @A.Wolff Tried it, it works thank you!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [eq()](https://api.jquery.com/eq/), to select the item you want:

> Given a jQuery object that represents a set of DOM elements, the .eq() method constructs a new jQuery object from one element within that set. The supplied index identifies the position of this element in the set.

```js
var $rows = $('#searchable tr');
$(document).ready(function() {
  $rows.eq(0).hide();
  console.log($rows[0])
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody id="searchable">
    <tr>
      <td>First Tr</td>
      <td>value1</td>
      <td>value2</td>
      <td>value3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Second Tr</td>
      <td>value1.2</td>
      <td>value2.2</td>
      <td>value3.2</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

---

Why `$rows[0]` doesn't work ??

Because `$()[index]` gives you the DOM Element // *Check the console on the snippet*; but in order to apply the `hide()` event you need the Jquery Object that is what `eq()` gives you.

For more reference [Get an element by index in jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9887534/get-an-element-by-index-in-jquery)

Comment: Thanks I've been searching for an hour and never came accross .eq(). Why is it that [] doesn't work?

Answer (score 1):

$rows.eq(0) instead of $rows[0]

Answer (score 0):

Use following

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#searchable tr").eq(0).hide();

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tbody id="searchable">
        <c:forEach var="lot" items="${pageResult.entries}" varStatus="status">
            <tr title="<c:out value='${lot.description}'/>">
            <td><c:out value='${lot.nom}'/></td>
            <td><fmt:formatNumber value="${lot.id}" pattern="0000"/></td>
            <td><c:out value='${lot.priorite}'/></td>
            <td>
                <form:form class="actionForm" action="detail" method="POST">
                    <input type="hidden" name="lotId" value="<c:out value='${lot.nom}'/>"/>
                    <input type="submit" class="action editer" value="Editer"/>
                </form:form>
                <form:form class="actionForm" action="supprimer" method="POST" onsubmit="return confirm('Confirmer la suppression?')">
                    <input type="hidden" name="lotId" value="<c:out value='${lot.nom}'/>"/>
                    <input type="submit" class="action supprimer" value="Supprimer"/>
                </form:form>
            </td></tr>
        </c:forEach>
</tbody>
  </table>
```