# How to get attributes from specific objects in an array using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've been trying to get the `class` attribute from an `label` element listed on an array.

I have two `label` elements with specific classes like so:

```
<label class="lblClass1">Answer 1
    <input type="radio" name="radioQ-1">
</label>
<label class="lblClass2">Answer 1
    <input type="radio" name="radioQ-1">
</label>
```

I'm looking for all the `label` elements with the following jQuery code:

```
var lblClass = $('label');
```

This will return both `label` elements as objects in an array, however I cannot get the attributes from a specific object in this array.

Let's say I want the `class` attribute from the second element in this array AKA lblClass2, I've tried something like this:

```
var ckbClass = $('label')[1].attr('class');
```

This approach gives me an error, however something like:

```
var ckbClass = $('label').attr('class');
```

Will successfully return the `class` attribute from the first elementon the array AKA lblClass1. This is probably due to some syntax error on jQuery that I don't understand yet.

Comment: Why is it that you need to get the `class` attribute? There may be an easier way of getting that done.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get an element by index in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9887534/get-an-element-by-index-in-jquery)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit** A better approach would be `$('label').eq(1).attr('class');`

---

Original Answer:

You would use something like: `$($('label')[1]).attr('class');`

Comment: You've created two jQuery objects for no reason. Use [`eq`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) instead.

Comment: Thanks a lot, now I understand why it wasn't working and how to better use jQuery.